# Cannot find the UseMysql method on DbContextOptions

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am playing around with the dotnet core on linux, and i am trying to configure my DbContext with a connection string to a mysql Server.

my DbContext looks like so:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Models.Entities;

namespace Models {
    public class SomeContext : DbContext
    {
        //alot of dbSets...
        public DbSet<SomeEntity> SomeDbSet { get; set; }

        public SomeContext(DbContextOptions<SomeContext> options) : base(options) {
            
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) 
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMysql //Cannot find this method
        }
        
        
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
        {
            //using modelBuilder to map some relationships
        }
    }
}
```

My dependencies looks like so:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc":"1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    "MySql.Data.Core": "7.0.4-ir-191",
    "MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.4-ir-191"
  },
```

I also tried to use the mysql server in my Startup.cs in the following code

```
public class Startup
    {
       
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.AspNetCore.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            services.AddDbContext<SomeContext>(options => options.UseMysql); //Cannot find UseMysql*
        }
```

I tried to change my directive from

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

to

```
using MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Which makes sense? maybe? but then all of the references to DbContext and DbSet is gone, so i suppose the solution is a mix of sorts??

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;
```

Oracle is not complying to the standard practices when using Dependency Injection, so its all a bit different. The standard practice is to put the extension methods for Depedency Injection into `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace, which is included in most ASP.NET Core app projects so the method becomes automatically available when a package is imported.

Comment: How did you figure out that MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions  was the exact "using statement" you had to use??

Comment: Hey, there is no way Oracle putting their code under `Microsoft.*` namespace :)

Comment: @IvanStoev: it's not any framework specific code, just the extension methods which are used to inject/register the Mysql provider, so `Microsoft.Extension.DependencyInjection` is perfectly well suited for it, because the code is **very specific** to the Dependency injection introduced in (ASP).NET Core

Comment: @DenLilleMand: It's a common naming convention to put extension methods in a namespace called `.Extensions` so they can be imported on demand and otherwise excluded.

Comment: @Tseng I was just kidding.

Comment: @gtzinos it's prerelease at present https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore/

Comment: `The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?`

Comment: 'MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions' is depricated!

Answer (score 21):

Use the below code if you are referencing the package **Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql**

```
 services.AddDbContextPool<AppDBContext>(options =>
        {
            var connetionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            options.UseMySql(connetionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connetionString));
        });
```

Answer (score 8):

Future readers.

If you are using "MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore":

I have this: (note, the cAsE of ***any*** word/phrase containing "**MySql**".)

In my top-layer (.exe usually) where I do the DI configuration.

csproj (top layer)

```
<PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.19" />
```

cs file with DI

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore;


///where servColl is IServiceCollection 
servColl.AddDbContext<MyCoolDbContext>(options => options.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=library;user=mysqlschema;password=mypassword"));
```

NOTE above the CASE of **UseMySQL**.  Why the namespace is "MySql" and the "use" is "UseMySQL" (??)...... this inconsistency (with the cAsE) is worth noting if you're hitting your head against the screen.  :)

and in the "lower layer" (my "data layer") where I code to EntityFramework Core (but not any specific concrete)

csproj (data layer) (note the 2.1 versions.......)

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.*" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="2.1.*" />
```

======================================

IF you are using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.  (Which I personally think is a better option.)

In my top-layer (.exe usually) where I do the DI configuration.

csproj (top layer)

```
 <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.1.*" />
```

cs file with DI

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure;


///where servColl is IServiceCollection 
servColl.AddDbContext<MyCoolDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql("server=localhost;database=library;user=mysqlschema;password=mypassword"));
```

NOTE above the CASE of **UseMySql**.  This is consistent.  So bonus points for Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql for consistency between the "using (namepsace)" and the DI registration "UseMySql".

and in the "lower layer" (my "data layer") where I code to EntityFramework Core (but not any specific concrete)

csproj (data layer)

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.*" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.1.*" />
```

Comment: Yup, that was it in my case (pun intended). Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you are not using `MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore` package. You could be using the `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` package for MySql on EntityFramework Core.

If so, add these lines:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore;
```