# .NET Core Pomelo Mysql connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to run a Entity Framework command in dotnet cli and I'm getting the following error:

> Access denied for user ''@'fe80::45b2:4add:f2de:ebcf%6' (using password: NO)

This is my code in Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "NetCoreApp.API", Version = "v1" });
            });

    string mySqlConnectionStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");  
    services.AddDbContextPool<DataContext>(options => options.UseMySql("server=localhost; port=3306; database=alohatest; user=netcore; password=0yetcxeY7MzThobL; Persist Security Info=False; Connect Timeout=300", ServerVersion.AutoDetect(mySqlConnectionStr)));
}
```

It's like EF doesn't take the correct connection string.

UPDATE:

Here is my full Exception:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext info
Build started...
Build succeeded.
The Entity Framework tools version '5.0.5' is older than that of the runtime '6.0.0-preview.3.21201.2'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes.
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user ''@'fe80::45b2:4add:f2de:ebcf%6' (using password: NO)
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ConnectAsync(ConnectionSettings cs, Int32 startTickCount, ILoadBalancer loadBalancer, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 494
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.ConnectSessionAsync(String logMessage, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 368
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 107
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.GetSessionAsync(MySqlConnection connection, Int32 startTickCount, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ConnectionPool.cs:line 137
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, Int32 startTickCount, Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in 
/_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 863
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable`1 ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 414   
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.Open() in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs:line 380
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion.AutoDetect(String connectionString)
   at NetCoreApp.API.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<ConfigureServices>b__1(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in C:\Proyectos\NetCoreApp\NetCoreApp.API\Startup.cs:line 40
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`2.<AddDbContextPool>b__0(IServiceProvider _, DbContextOptionsBuilder ob)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.<AddPoolingOptions>b__0(IServiceProvider sp, DbContextOptionsBuilder ob)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateDbContextOptions[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<AddCoreServices>b__0(IServiceProvider p)       
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.ResolveService(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, RuntimeResolverLock lockType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)     
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__17`1.<AddCoreServices>b__17_1(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.ResolveService(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, RuntimeResolverLock lockType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)     
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.ResolveService(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, RuntimeResolverLock lockType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)     
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetServices[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextTypes()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.FindContextType(String name)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.GetContextInfo(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.GetContextInfoImpl(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.GetContextInfo.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Access denied for user ''@'fe80::45b2:4add:f2de:ebcf%6' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: Why do you have two connection strings ?

Comment: I Just use one conection. I made a test passing de string conection to de UseMysql function, is de same a have in appsettings.json.

Comment: This is a wild guess, but have you tried removing the whitespace after the semicolons? I'm not sure those are not preserved, in which case, it's only grabbing the "server=localhost" part from it because the rest of the keys would have a leading whitespace. Again, not sure, but it's the first time in my life I see a connection string with spaces after semicolons

Comment: @GermanKinen post your original code then, don't assume that all tutorials and courses are wrong.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos at least Pomelo allows `user` and `password` as keys (although the correct is `uid` and `pwd`), that's for sure

Comment: @Jcl the error complains there's user *and* no password. Something is definitely wrong with the connection string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree, but it also doesn't show the correct user, that's why I suspected about the whitespaces (seems it's only getting the `server=localhost` part, and the rest of the keys -might- be parsed as `<whitespace>user=something`, `<whitespace>password=something`, but again, just a wild guess, I'm not sure and can't test right now

Comment: See possible helper answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059929/cannot-find-the-usemysql-method-on-dbcontextoptions/61351354#61351354. also, i would REMOVE the WHITESPACE in your connection string.

Comment: Can you please post full exception? there should be stacktrace

Comment: Do you run `dotnet ef dbcontext info` from same folder as you have appconfig.json??

Comment: I do not understand the question

Answer (score 3):

**.Net6**

In .net6 there are no *startup.cs* therefore you need to do the hardwork inside program.cs as follows:

**program.cs:**

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options =>
{
    string connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
}
);
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection":"server=***;database=***;uid=***;pwd=***"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're having an issue because of whitespace.

Take out the whitespace in the connection string.

Example:

```
servColl.AddDbContext<MyCoolDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql("server=localhost;database=library;user=mysqlschema;password=mypassword"));
```

Get that working (the hard coded string value).

THEN (after hard coding works)... put the connection-string inside the appSettings.json

Comment: Actually getting this in net 6.0 using Pomelo with _context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString strips password odd.

Comment: For security purposes, the "Getter" ("GetDbConnection" in this case)... will strip out the "secret" (aka the password).  It is on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I took out the whitespace in the connection string and moved connection string to config, but a have the same error.

That is my code:

Start up:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "NetCoreApp.API", Version = "v1" });
            });

            string mySqlConnectionStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");  
            services.AddDbContextPool<DataContext>(options => options.UseMySql(mySqlConnectionStr, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(mySqlConnectionStr)));
        }
```

appsetting.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },  
    "ConnectionStrings": {  
      "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;port=3306;database=alohatest;user=netcore;password=0yetcxeY7MzThobL;Persist Security Info=False;Connect Timeout=300"  
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: Update your question not answer