# How to use asp.net core 6 with MySQL

Tags: mysql, .net-6.0

Create a project in Visual Studio.

Open Program.cs

Replace:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

For:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>  
    options.UseMySql(connectionString, new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(5, 7))));
```

Visual Studio will advertise you for an error.

Accept the suggestion and install package "Pomelo..."

Open appsettings.json and replace the SqlServer DefaultConnection with your MySQL values.
Something like:

```
"DefaultConnection": "server=your.server.com;user=your_user;password=your_pw;database=your_dbname;port=3306"
```

remove-migration (all of them)

add-migration

update-database

Done

Everything else works like the same.

Comment: It won't work with .net core 6.
With .net core 6, for now, you have to use Pomelo...

Comment: btw. .net-6 is not called core.

Comment: Sorry, I mean asp.net core

Answer (score 1):

1. 

Make sure you are using

```
<PackageReference Include="MySql.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.10" />
```

Obviously, the value for the Version above will change (increment) over time.

see:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.EntityFrameworkCore/6.0.10#dependencies-body-tab

(to make it clear, make sure you are NOT using the below (**similarly** named, but **abandoned**)

```
<PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.22" />
```

See the below url.  note there are not versions in recent dates because it has been abandoned.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore/

2.

Consider a change (which is my personal preference between the two)

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Bonus tip:

When "fishing" at nuget.org .. always look at the "Dependencies" and "Frameworks" ("tabs" on the gui of nuget page)....

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#dependencies-body-tab

Bonus Tip #2.

Always post your csproj contents with dependency questions.  At least the germane portions of your csproj files.

Extra:

See my answer here:

[Cannot find the UseMysql method on DbContextOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059929/cannot-find-the-usemysql-method-on-dbcontextoptions/61351354#61351354)

There are "cAsE iSsuEs" with the MySql/MYSQL using statements to watch carefully.